# issues with bonding

Tags: 22.04, netplan, network-bonding

I have enabled nic bonding with vlans on my ubuntu 22.04 machine with 2 interfaces. One of the interfaces is connected to Switch 1 and the other one goes to Switch2. Here is what happening, when i bring down the port connected to switch 1 , i am unable to ping the machine. Ideally it should automatically be available via the switch 2 port, but its not. Network guy says he is not able to learn the MAC from the other interface and there is no other config needed to be done on switch layer when its active-backup bonding, which seems to be true.

Here is what my bonding looks like in netplan configuration file. Is there a problem in the config file? Let me know pls.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno12399np0:
      dhcp4: no
    eno12409np1:
      dhcp4: no
    eno8303:
      dhcp4: no
    eno8403:
      dhcp4: no
    enp177s0f0np0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp177s0f1np1:
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces: [enp177s0f0np0, eno12409np1]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: enp177s0f0np0
    bond1:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces: [enp177s0f1np1, eno12399np0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/27]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: enp177s0f1np1
  vlans:
    vlan209:
      id: 209
      link: bond0
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [100.100.50.75/27]
      gateway4: 100.100.50.65
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Thanks. Those are 2 different bonds altogether with different sets of interfaces. However on bond0 I have created a vlan as the 2 interfaces are allowed with trunk on switches.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it with my last comment.  Unfortunately, I have never been good with Netplan on this stuff.  I do have a 20.04 LTS server and I got rid of Netplan on it as I wanted bonding as well on it, so I went strictly with `ifupdown` and have not had any issues with it.  I also run it with adaptive load balancing or `balance-alb` since it does have backup and moves the load to either NIC depending on traffic.  I gave you an upvote to help with visual here hoping someone has experience in this.

Comment: Thanks, @Terrance. Hoping someone would help me out here.

Comment: Additionally, i have noticed that the slave doesn't change to the secondary one automatically when the primary one is down. I am not sure what is happening. I manually changed it using ifenslave -c bond0 <secondary interface> and then it works...

Comment: Maybe try the `balance-alb` instead of `active-backup` as it uses both interfaces to help the load, and it is a backup as well supporting fail-over.

Answer (score 0):

It's cool that the Ubuntu installer supports bonding, but when you choose the "active-backup" option it IMO leaves you with a non functional configuration. The MII link monitoring is off by default.

Try to apply the following on your bonding interfaces to see if it makes any difference:

```
          parameters:
              mode: active-backup
              mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

It's also possible to temporarily enable link monitoring on a bonding interface like this (as root):

```
echo "100" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/miimon
```

To list properties of a bonding interface do this:

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
```

HTH,
Mikael

Comment: Ok. Let me try this